# Class 'Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector' not found

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, composer-php

I'm setting a Laravel project into a server, but I had this problem when I used "composer install". I have done exactly the same in local, followed the same tutorials and I didn't have this problem.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 for both.

Here is my `composer.json` file.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
}
}
```

And the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector' not found in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php on line 78


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector' not found
```

There is no problem in the laravel project, it seems to be any failure in the installation. Any idea of how to add the missing Class?.

Comment: try n change composer code mapping like this [url](https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher/commit/0e3ab1948e094e413211fa6fffd69506d41bd8ca)

Comment: Have you tried "composer dump-autoload" ? It's the "turn it off and on again" of Laravel and namespaces.

Comment: I already tried changing the code like that Swapper, and Amarnasan i did it now and nothing changed.

Comment: experiencing this right now

Comment: Did anyone come right with this. I'm getting it on a Symfony project.

Comment: i'm having the same issue